# Как при записи данных в файл, убрать последний элемент?

Tags: python, строки, scripts

У меня есть скрипт:

```
count = 0
with open('final_1.geojson', 'w') as fin:
    fin.write('{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [')
    with open('long_1.txt', 'r') as long:
        for i in long:
            i_1, i_2 = i.split()
            with open('short_1.txt', 'r') as short:
                for k in short: 
                    k_1, k_2 = k.split()
                    string = '{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": ' +str(count)+'}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[['+str(i_1) + ',' + str(k_1)+ ']'+',' + '[' + str(i_2)+','+str(k_1) + ']'+',' + '['+str(i_2)+ ',' + str(k_2) +'],'  + '[' + str(i_1)+ ',' + str(k_2) +']]]}},' 
                    fin.write(string)
                    count+=1
    end = ']}'
    fin.write(end)
```

Общая логика такая: Скрипт проходит по файлам, вытягивает из них нужные значения и складывает в новый файл в нужном мне виде.

В скрипте есть перменная `string`. В конце переменной есть запятая `','`
Мне надо, чтобы эта запятая была у всех `string`, кроме последнего значения.

Сейчас у меня вот так:

```
"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.009,10.005394],[5.01,10.005394],[5.01,10.006293],[5.009,10.006293]]]}},{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 86}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.009,10.006293],[5.01,10.006293],[5.01,10.007192],[5.009,10.007192]]]}},{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 87}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.009,10.007192],[5.01,10.007192],[5.01,10.008091],[5.009,10.008091]]]}},{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 88}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.009,10.008091],[5.01,10.008091],[5.01,10.00899],[5.009,10.00899]]]}},{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 89}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.009,10.00899],[5.01,10.00899],[5.01,10.009889],[5.009,10.009889]]]}},]}
```

Должно быть вот так:

```
"geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.009,10.005394],[5.01,10.005394],[5.01,10.006293],[5.009,10.006293]]]}},{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 86}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.009,10.006293],[5.01,10.006293],[5.01,10.007192],[5.009,10.007192]]]}},{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 87}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.009,10.007192],[5.01,10.007192],[5.01,10.008091],[5.009,10.008091]]]}},{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 88}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.009,10.008091],[5.01,10.008091],[5.01,10.00899],[5.009,10.00899]]]}},{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": 89}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[5.009,10.00899],[5.01,10.00899],[5.01,10.009889],[5.009,10.009889]]]}}]}
```

Посмотрите в конец двух строк. 
Вместо '`}},]}`' в первой строке я хочу сделать '`}}]}`' для последнего значения.
Как убрать запятую с последнего значения в цыкле?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря, писать JSON можно гораздо проще, работая с dict.

```py
import json

count = 0
data = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': []
}

with open('long_1.txt', 'r') as long:
    for i in long:
        i_1, i_2 = i.split()
        with open('short_1.txt', 'r') as short:
            for k in short:
                k_1, k_2 = k.split()
                data['features'].append({
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'properties': {
                        'area': str(count),
                    },
                    'geometry': {
                        'type': 'Polygon',
                        'coordinates': [[
                            [str(i_1), str(k_1)],
                            [str(i_2), str(k_1)],
                            [str(i_2), str(k_2)],
                            [str(i_1), str(k_2)]
                        ]]
                    }
                })
                count += 1

with open('final_1.geojson', 'w') as fin:
    fin.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Upd.

Решение:

Добавить переменную `file_is_empty`, которая будет говорить нам о том, что в файл мы ничего не записывали, и убрать в конце строки запятую.

При первой итерации - запишется строка без запятой. При второй и последующих итерациях переменная `file_is_empty` уже будет иметь значение `False`, а тогда в переменную `string` добавится запятая в самое начало. По окончанию цикла будет валидный json без проблемной запятой в конце.

```py
count = 0
file_is_empty = True
with open('final_1.geojson', 'w') as fin:
    fin.write('{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [')
    with open('long_1.txt', 'r') as long:
        for i in long:
            i_1, i_2 = i.split()
            with open('short_1.txt', 'r') as short:
                for k in short:
                    k_1, k_2 = k.split()
                    string = '' if file_is_empty else ','
                    string += '{"type": "Feature", "properties": {"area": ' +str(count)+'}, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[['+str(i_1) + ',' + str(k_1)+ ']'+',' + '[' + str(i_2)+','+str(k_1) + ']'+',' + '['+str(i_2)+ ',' + str(k_2) +'],'  + '[' + str(i_1)+ ',' + str(k_2) +']]]}}'
                    fin.write(string)
                    file_is_empty = False
                    count+=1
    end = ']}'
    fin.write(end)
```

Comment: Согласен с вами. Этот вариант не подойдет к сожалению, так как data будет храниться в оперативной памяти.У меня меня очень большой объем данных и оперативки не хватит мне для этих нужд.  Чтобы не хранить все в оперативке, я хочу записывать построчно данные в файл.

Comment: @ivan100096, дополнил ответ.

Comment: огромное спасибо, работает)